# php function printing out first choice only

Tags: javascript, beginner, php

Look at the code below. When I run the program. Only 'You're still a pup!...' gets printed out. No matter how high of a number I put. I DO know that it is taking the correct number because I echoed out the age to test separately.

```
<?php
    function prompt($prompt_msg){
    echo("<script type='text/javascript'> var answer = prompt('".$prompt_msg."'); </script>");

    $answer = "<script type='text/javascript'> document.write(answer); </script>";
    return($answer);
    }

    $prompt_msg = "Please type your age.";
    $age = prompt($prompt_msg);


    if (18 > $age)
    {
        echo("You're still a pup! Stay in school.");
    } elseif (29 > $age)
    {
        echo("This is the prime of your life-- Enjoy it!");
    } elseif (39 > $age)
    {
        echo("This is the time to focus on your career!");
    } elseif (49 > $age)
    {
        echo("These might be your prime earning years.");
    } elseif (59 > $age)
    {
        echo("Time to get ready for retirement.");
    } else
    {
        echo("What's life's next adventure?");
    }

    echo("<br/>"); ?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Broken code](http://meta.CodeReview.StackExchange.com/a/3650) is off-topic for this site. Please [follow the tour](http://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/tour) and read ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask), ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing javascript and php.  The php code is run on the server when the page is loaded.  It will never see the value from the javascript code that is run on the client after the page is loaded.

If you want to use javascript and php like this, you will need to do an ajax call to the php code

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions.